# Sharepoint REST API authentication with SAML

Tags: rest, authentication, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, okta

My app uses OKTA for authentication using SAML. I was able to get this up. I am also able to make REST calls to sharepoint using the username and password.

Now that I have both these set up, I would like to integrate them. I would like to use OKTA(SAML) for authentication and then would like to use the SAML token for authentication of REST calls. (I am using sipmlesamlphp library for implementing the SAML authentication)

I would like to know if Sharepoint REST API supports it and if yes what headers should I pass for the same.

Comment: Hi, how did you achieve it? Please help me,